# t-sql: CONTAINS() returns rows but cannot find searched text strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing a simple query like the one below:

```
SELECT TEXT
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CONTAINS(TEXT, 'ab')
```

This query returns some rows. However, in some of these return rows, I cannot locate the string 'ab' in the TEXT column. It's quite puzzling. I wonder what might be the cause of this.

Just to add, if I use `WHERE TEXT LIKE '%[^a-z]ab[^a-z]%', those rows where I cannot locate 'ab' are not returned.

Comment: look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) which says `Searches for precise or fuzzy (less precise) matches to single words and phrases`

Comment: Please post a sample of the rows from your table together with a sample of the faulty output.

Comment: The complication is that this is my work data, and I cannot put it online

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the smaller, or not meaningful, it is the word to search, the more likely it is that the search also retrieves texts not perfectly matching to it, further to specify the exact string to search you have include your string into double quotes (`'"ab"'`)..

therefore, try with this:

```
SELECT TEXT
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CONTAINS(TEXT, '"ab"')
```

you should have only the words composed by only the string 'ab', but consider that as [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) says:

> < simple_term > 
>   
>  Specifies a match for an exact word or a phrase.
>   Examples of valid simple terms are "blue berry", blueberry, and
>   "Microsoft SQL Server". Phrases should be enclosed in double quotation
>   marks (""). Words in a phrase must appear in the same order as
>   specified in  as they appear in the
>   database column. The search for characters in the word or phrase is
>   not case-sensitive. Noise words (or [stopwords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx)) (such as a, and, or
>   the) in full-text indexed columns are not stored in the full-text
>   index. If a noise word is used in a single word search, SQL Server
>   returns an error message indicating that the query contains only noise
>   words. SQL Server includes a standard list of noise words in the
>   directory \Mssql\Binn\FTERef of each instance of SQL Server.
>
> **Punctuation is ignored. Therefore, CONTAINS(testing, "computer
>   failure") matches a row with the value, "Where is my computer? Failure
>   to find it would be expensive." For more information on word-breaker
>   behavior, see [Configure and Manage Word Breakers and Stemmers for Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142509.aspx)**.

Comment: But that's not what I want. I want to search `ab` by itself. If I do `*ab*`, I will get a ton of irrelevant and useless results.

Comment: I only want search for `ab` as a standalone word, not words like `about` and `tabulate`. The last two examples contain "ab", but they are not what I want and are irrelevant.

Comment: Didn't seem so from your OP.. however in this case you shouldn't use "contains" but simply: text = 'ab'

Comment: try WHERE CONTAINS(TEXT, '"ab"')